# Problems with "withRouter" and redux's "connect()"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I'm trying to implement react-router with my react-redux app, but I am getting this error message:

> Layout(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

I copy-pasted everything from the [tutorial](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html) from the redux website and added my already existing redux-using component.

My Layout.js:

```js
import React from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import { fetchIdeas } from "../actions/ideasActions"

import Ideas from "../components/Ideas"


class Layout extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchIdeas())
  }

  render() {
    const { ideas } = this.props;
    return 
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <Ideas ideas={ideas}/>
      </div>
  }
}

export default withRouter(
  connect((store) => {
 return {
   ideas: store.ideas,
 };
  })(Layout)
)
```

What exactly did I do wrong? I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Not sure what's in the Ideas component. If you comment it out will it run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic JavaScript mistake. `return` cannot be on its own line like that.

```
return // returns undefined
  <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <Ideas ideas={ideas}/>
  </div>
```

fix!

```
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <Ideas ideas={ideas}/>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Ah, Azium is right. If you move the 'div' onto the same line as the return it will work as well

Comment: @user2465134 yeah but that looks ugly :p I recommend prettier for greater good https://github.com/prettier/prettier

Comment: @azium I agree :p